# pagination with cgridview in yii

Tags: php, yii, pagination, modal-dialog, cgridview

I have created a page that shows all the data in CGridView with pagination and for each row i had an Edit and Delete links .

when we click on Edit link modal popup appears with that perticular row data .

after making changes when we click button on popup ,that data should be updated and that popup should be closed and the data from table should be displayed in CGridView with pagination and without reloading page...

.I had done all but while after update the is displaying data in CGridView with pagination but pagination is showing twice  , for updated one and for previous one..

so how to restrict this pagination to once without reloading.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Thanks for reply....i had solved that by putting pagintaion to false to cgridview dataprovider..

Comment: had another error....for other page

Comment: yes.......................